# Where is the simulate location button in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode5

In Xcode 4, we have a simulate location button right next to the step out button like in this picture:

[image]

But in Xcode 5, we don't have it anymore, does anybody know where it went?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you still can set that from debug tap like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Debug ----> Simulate Location.

[image]

Comment: wow, you guys are so fast and awesome. both answers are the same and posted at the same time. i don't know which one to accept, i guess you have much more reputation than him, i will vote both you guys up and accept his. Thanks so much!